# Big Summation Sign

Tags: amsmath

i want to change the Summation Sign so thats as big as the text i wrote after.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$\sum C_i$
\end{document}
```

How can i change it like in the following picture ?

[image: Summationsign]

why the rest of my code is not in the right code sample???

Comment: "why the rest of my code is not in the right code sample??? " Code sample markdown is not applied automatically. To apply it, you have to highlight all of the code and hit ctrl+k, or press the code sample button -- the one like {} What these shortcuts do is add four spaces at the start of each line. That is the actual markdown for code sample, and you can enter it yourself. You must leave a blank line between text and a code block, otherwise the formatting will not apply. The reason just a bit of your code was formatted is that that bit had four spaces (and then some more) at the start

Comment: And it followed a blank line. All code after that had the four spaces at the start (and some more) and so was formatted too. But the rest of the code, although it had four (or more) spaces at the start, there was no line break, so formatting was not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require `\displaystyle` for the formula, but this will probably change the interlining locally, especially if there are bounds for the sum. Another solution would be to use `\medop` from `nccmath`, which defines a bunch of medium-sized commands for formulae (~80 % of `displaystyle`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{nccmath}

 \begin{document}

$\sum C_i$\qquad
$\displaystyle\sum C_i$\qquad
$\medop\sum C_i$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the medop solution is awesome , but i still dont get how i put a code right in this community

Comment: The simplest is to highlight the code with your mouse  and click on the ‘code’ icon in the toolbar of the editing window  (the  pair of braces, on the left of the mountain logo).

Comment: thx@bernard that helped me alot!